# When unchecked the angular material checkbox array is not updating in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material

I am displaying data which are selected from modal. And by unselecting it I am removing data from array. Now when I unselecting any of data, data is made checked: false and not displaying, but when reopen the modal unselected data is showing selected.

**ts file from which modal is opening:**

```
postGraduate = [
    {
      text: 'Magistar',
      checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Master',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Doktor nauka',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Specijalista',
        checked: false
    }
  ];
therapistDetails = {
postGraduate: ['Magistar', 'Master', 'Doktor nauka', 'Specijalista']
}

if(this.therapistdetails.postGraduate && this.therapistdetails.postGraduate.length) {
   this.therapistdetails.postGraduate.forEach(element => {
     this.postGraduate.forEach((graduate) => {
        if(graduate.text == element) {
           graduate.checked = true;
         }
      })
    });
   }

addGraduationModal() {
    const graduation = {
      title: 'Graduation',
      data: this.postGraduate
    }
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: graduation,
    })
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('after closed value... ', result);
      if (result && result.action && result.action == 'graduation') {
        this.therapistdetails.postGraduate = response.graduation;        
      }
    })
  }
```

**html file:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngIf="therapistdetails.postGraduate">
    <div *ngFor="let postgraduate of therapistdetails.postGraduate; let i =index" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="row ">
         <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
             <p class="check-box">
             <mat-checkbox [checked]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]"> 
             </mat-checkbox>
             </p>
           </div>
          <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
             <p class="master">
             <mat-form-field                                                  
               floatPlaceholder="never"                                                   
               class="margin-top-25px">
              <input                                                   
               class="input"                                                     
               matInput                                      
               [(ngModel)]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]"
               placeholder="Year of graduation" >
            </mat-form-field>
             </p>       
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <p class="Addmore pointer" (click)="addGraduationModal()" >Add More</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**modal ts file:**

```
constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    }
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.data.data && this.data.data.length) {
      this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        items: this.formBuilder.array([ ])
      })

      this.setCheckBoxValue();
    }
  }

  setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
      this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        text: element.text,
        checked: element.checked,
      }))
    });
  }

  onCloseConfirm() {
    if(this.data.title == 'Graduation') {
      this.thisDialogRef.close({ 
        action: 'graduation', 
        postGraduate: this.orderForm ? this.orderForm.controls.items.value.filter((value) => value.checked == true) : []
      });
    }
  }
```

** modal template file:**

```
<div>
  <h2 mat-dialog-title> {{data.title}} </h2>
  <hr>

  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div *ngIf="data.data.length" [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls;let i=index">
        <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" >
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked" name="selected" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.checked.value" >
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" >
            <mat-form-field 
            floatPlaceholder="never" class="margin-top-25px example-full-width" >
                <input 
                matInput
                class="input" name="checked"
                formControlName="text"
                value="{{item.controls.text.value}}"               
                >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>

  <div>
    <hr>
    <mat-dialog-actions style="float: right">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCloseCancel()" class="btn-style-cancell">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCloseConfirm()"
       class="btn-style">Confirm</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I unchecked the checkbox. postGraduate[] is not updating. Please help me out..

Comment: there are some strange in your code: your Modal return an array, e.g. `[{text: 'Magistar', checked: true},{text: 'Doktor nauka',checked: true}]`, but you want show all the list of therapistdetails.postGraduate, it's not better you return the full array -checked or not checked-?. It's strange too that you create a FormArray of formGroup with the controls "name" and "checked", it's not better a FormArray only with booleans?

Comment: @Eliseo, In modal I have to show selected text which are probably come from database. And that selected value can be unselect or remain as it is by user. I took two fields one for text and second for checkbox true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Use [(ngModel)] instead [checked]

Replace

```
[checked]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]"
```

with

```
[(ngModel)]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]"
```

Comment: You are passing complete object. Your ```therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]``` is an object. Please pass boolean instead. In your case it will be ```[(ngModel)]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i][1]" ``` please try this

Comment: From comments with @hekany, got the proper understanding regarding this.. By applying ```[checked]="therapistdetails.postGraduate[i]"``` this, checkbox got selected..

Answer (score 0):

Use change event. Call one function on change like this :

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="checked" name="selected" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.checked.value" (change)="isChecked($event, item)" >
</mat-checkbox>
```

where, $event gives you checkbox is checked or unchecked and item is your item that you want to add in an array.

In ts like this you can implement:

```
isChecked(e, item) {

}
```

Comment: NOT use [checked] is you has a formControlName or ngModel, control if is checked by the valur of the form

Comment: @Eliseo, If I do not use [checked] then what should I use?

Comment: you give value to the Control. If you're using [(ngModel)]="variable", variable=true/false, if your use a formControl, when create the formControl `new FormControl(true)`, or using setValue, e.g. `myForm.get('control').setValue(true)`or with formBuilder.... When you using ReactiveForm or [ngModel] you yet say the value of the "input". if futhermore you use [checked] are give twice the "value" -one in variable and another one as "attributte". This is confused

Comment: Do one thing remove formControlName and set value to this form control in isChecked function.

Comment: @Eliseo, yes.. I am actually getting confused. I have set the values in group using formBuilder. And it is not throwing me any error. I guess you are trying to say that I can only assign value with setValue(). The way I assigned is wrong. Is it so?

Comment: @Tushar, Why to remove formControlName?

Comment: No, @JaynaTanawala, you can give value in severals ways, one is when you create the formGroup -using formBuilder or directatly iusing the constructor-, another one is using setValue. About your code, you change this.therapistdetails.postGraduate and equal to an array of object [{text:..,checked:true},{text:..,checked:true}) -I supouse you need a "map" in a onCloseConfirm() `postGraduate: this.orderForm ? this.orderForm.controls.items.value.filter((value) => value.checked == true).map(x=>x.text) : []`. But then I can not understand your main.html

Comment: Okay. @Eliseo, I understand slightly your point. And Thanks for putting efforts..

Answer (score 0):

[checked] expect a boolean value however you are using `therapistdetails.postGraduate` which is an array of strings.

I think you should use `postGraduate` like:

```
<div *ngFor="let pg of postGraduate;" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    ...
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pg.checked"></mat-checkbox>
    ...
```

Comment: @hakanyBy doing this, checkbox is not coming as selected. By doing therapistdetails.postGraduate[i] I got the checkbox selected.

Comment: to be sure; is the `if`-statement in the ts script like you have it above? so not in a constructor and not in a ngOnInit method? The reason why I'm asking this is, the if statement could not be triggered if this is the case and therefore it won't be selected. Could you check this please.

Comment: please also check stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tmvqe

Comment: Yes @hakany, I just made one function call in ngOnInit() and in that function I am doing which I described in the question. But why is it so?

Comment: Typescript cannot handle logic code which isn't in a function/method. Some IDE's will also show an error if this is not the case.

Comment: such kind of logic should be defined in the constructor or ngOnInit (if the class implements OnInit) which are always the start when the class will be initialized

Comment: Okay.. Thank you @hakany for this knowledge. I will keep in mind this..